"Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." showing error even with key?
I'm trying to fetch from my Facilities table and render it in a table but I'm getting a "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop" warning in my console.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import supabase from './createClient';
import './App.css'; // style sheet

const App = () => {
    const [facilities, setFacilities] = useState([]); // define it so we can call it

    // every time we load our page we run this particular function
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchFacilities();
    }, []);

    async function fetchFacilities() {
        // fetch from supabase and store it in state
        const { data } = await supabase
            .from('facilities') // SQL-like query
            .select('*');
            setFacilities(data); // set state for facilities
            console.log(data)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>facilityid</th>
                        <th>name of facility</th>
                        <th>location of facility</th>
                        <th>type of facility</th>
                        <th>facility address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {facilities.map((facility) => 
                        <tr>
                            <td>{facility.facilityID}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityName}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityLocation}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityType}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityAddress}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>

                
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;

Adding the key={facility.facilityID} in my <tr> tag
                <tbody>
                    {facilities.map((facility) => 
                        <tr key={facility.facilityID}>
                            <td>{facility.facilityID}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityName}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityLocation}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityType}</td>
                            <td>{facility.facilityAddress}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>

but I still got the error. I did notice that the console.log(data) prints the Facilities table twice.
These are the specific warnings if I press show more


Embarrassing oversight: my variables were all lowercased in supabase. I had created the database with casing
CREATE TABLE Facilities (
  facilityID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  facilityType TEXT,
  facilityLocation TEXT,
  facilityName VARCHAR(100),
  facilityAddress TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(facilityID)
);

but for some reason the table editor shows the headers with them all lowercased...

So how did you fix your issue?

I just had to access the variables from my frontend with the lowercased text instead of the camelcasing that I did in my inserts i.e., <td>{facility.facilityname}</td> instead of  <td>{facility.facilityName}</td>
